# BASE_URL - GODADY - system codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting, base-url

I would need some help, I have go-dady hosting and sub-domain. I also have simple HTML website that is included in codeigniter system. The problem is that main page works (http://new.bendcare.com), but all sub-pages doesn't work, i get error:

```
No input file specified.
```

My base url in set:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://new.bendcare.com';
```

My current .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I found that I should add #Mod Rewrite on godady hosting to work correctly, but not in my case.

What should I change to make codigniter work on godady hosting ? I have no problems on other hosting's.

Comment: Where have you placed the .htaccess it should be out side of application folder. don't touch the .htaccess that's in the application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ? sign after index.php in the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And it would work !